# How to check Java 6 code in Java 5?

Tags: testing, java-6, java-5

Does anybody know of a good approach for testing Java 6 code in Java 5? I just finished writing some programs for an internship application in Java 6, only to realize that they wanted me to submit code written in Java 5. I use eclipse, so I tried setting a duplicate project to run in a J2SE-1.5 environment and it worked. Was that a proper test, or was I mistaking something else for a Java 5? I also tried finding an online Java 5 compiler to test my code, but I couldn't find any websites with versions earlier than Java 6. I don't have a whole lot of experience with the more technical aspects of this sort of thing, so any simple approach would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: Just make sure you have a 1.5JDK and a 1.6JDK installed and then flip between them in Eclipse through the Windows -> Preferences menu

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I think testing in a J2SE-1.5 environment should do it. Did you also change your compiler settings in the "Properties" window to 1.5? Please check that and try running your code. As far as I know I only do this to test between different versions of Java.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I went to the properties window and changed the compiler settings to 1.5 like you said, and it worked. Though it might be worth mentioning that I've been running my code from the command line, because it needs to take external files in through the main method.

Comment: I wish I could, but I don't have 15 reputation -_- Needing reputation to vote up seems kind of stupid to me.

Comment: @Warman Steve You can accept his answer if it has helped you.